# Remove spaces in file names apache

Tags: php, apache, upload

1.Hi, I have a internal use only file upload script that uploads the files to a directory. When I upload something from my computer with a spcace in the name i.e example 1.zip it uploads with a space in the name thus killing the link in a email. Is it possible to make apache remove the space when its uploaded or make it a underscore?

The second problem I am having is how would I parse this to make the link an email link with the url of the file as the body of the email amd the email addy anything?

```
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $uploaddir . $_FILES['file']['name'])) {
    // uploaded file was moved and renamed succesfuly. Display a message.
    echo "Link: " . "http://example.org/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You just need to [`urlencode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) your file name and everything is fine:

```
echo "Link: http://example.org/" . urlencode($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
```

But if you want to remove the spaces for another reason, you can use [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php):

```
$replaced_name = str_replace(' ', '_', $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
rename($uploaddir . '/' . $_FILES['file']['name'], $uploaddir . '/' . $replaced_name);
# You should urlencode() it nonetheless:
echo "Link: http://example.org/" . urlencode($replaced_name);
```

Comment: How would I make it so I could use that link as a mailto like the link would go on the body and anything would be in the message

Comment: Have a look at the examples section of the according RFC: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2368#section-6

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$filename = $_FILES['file']['name'];
$filename = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/", "", $filename);

//then
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $uploaddir . $filename)) {

// uploaded file was moved and renamed succesfuly. Display a message.
echo "Link: " . "http://example.org/" . $filename;
```

Comment: Thanks! any ide on how I would do an email like thing

Comment: You want to send this link for an email?

Comment: Basically I want it to echo a mailto:random@random.com with the body text at the link .

Comment: You can use mailto:stuff@random.com?body=http://example.com/file.zip. For a complete reference on mailto check: http://www.ianr.unl.edu/internet/mailto.html :)

Answer (score 1):

As a side note : with the code you are using, what is happening if two files with the same name are uploaded ? If you don't do a check (like "*is there a file that already has that name in `$uploaddir` ?*") the second file will replace the first one.

That might not be something you want... is it ?

If not, to solve that (potential) problem, one solution is to always rename uploaded files, with names **you** control. *(A simple counter would probably to the trick)*

Another thing is : `$_FILES["file"]["name"]` is sent by the client, and, as such, can probably be forged to contains whatever someone would want. If it contains something like "`../../index.php`" *(or something like this - you get the idea)*, this could allow someone to put any file they want on your server.

To prevent this from happening, you shoud be sure the file name/path used as destination of  `move_uploaded_file` does not contain anything "dangerous". A solution could be to use [`basename`](http://php.net/basename). (see, for instance, example #2 on [POST method uploads](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php))

You might also want to check the mimetype of the uploaded file, so you don't get executables, for instance -- and you should make sure files uploaded are not executable by the webserver.